# How can I compile SDL2 and GLEW applications statically on Linux?

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl-2, static-linking, glew

I am attempting to compile an OpenGl application that uses SDL2 and GLEW in such a way that it will run on any version of Linux it may find itself -- not just where it was originally compiled. To do this, I have tried several things none of which work.

I have tried directly linking to .a files produced by running make in the extracted root directory of GLEW and SDL from each library's website download. This produces the following errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /opt/SDL2-2.0.4/build/.libs/libSDL2.a(SDL_syssem.o): undefined reference to symbol 'sem_getvalue@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

I have tried building as I do with dynamically linked libraries, which works fine except for the cross-platform capabilities, (with `pkg-config --libs sdl2` and `pkg-config --libs glew`) but adding `-static`, at which point I get the following errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGLEW
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
```

When I change the previous scenario to point to my statically compiled GLEW libraries, I get undefined reference errors to OpenGl functions along with undefined reference errors like the following from many SDL functions. Adding -lGL does not change anything.

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2.a(SDL_dynapi.o): In function `SDL_InitDynamicAPI':
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2.a(SDL_dynapi.o): In function `SDL_InitDynamicAPI':
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2.a(SDL_dynapi.o): In function `SDL_InitDynamicAPI':
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2.a(SDL_sysloadso.o): In function `SDL_LoadObject_REAL':
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2.a(SDL_sysloadso.o): In function `SDL_LoadObject_REAL':
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2.a(SDL_sysloadso.o): In function `SDL_LoadFunction_REAL':
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2.a(SDL_sysloadso.o): In function `SDL_LoadFunction_REAL':
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2.a(SDL_sysloadso.o): In function `SDL_LoadFunction_REAL':
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2.a(SDL_sysloadso.o): In function `SDL_UnloadObject_REAL':
```

When I try using `pkg-config --libs --static <library name>` for all libraries, I get the following error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2.a(SDL_dynapi.o): In function `SDL_InitDynamicAPI':
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lasound
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpulse-simple
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpulse
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsndio
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwayland-egl
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-cursor.a(libwayland_cursor_la-xcursor.o): In function `XcursorImagesDestroy':
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.a(file.o):(.text+0x7d0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGLEW
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.a(GetDflt.o): In function `GetHomeDir.part.0':
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.a(GetDflt.o): In function `GetHomeDir.part.0':
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.a(xim_trans.o): In function `_XimXTransSocketINETConnect':
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

NOTE: All of the output above is from the command `g++ -o /path/to/outputExecutable <list of object files>.o <libraries as described above>`

NOTE: I do not think this question is a duplicate of any other question on the Stack Exchange network because I have been trying to figure this out for about one and a half months and I have seen a very large number of these questions and tried everything in them, thus, even if the symptoms are the same the underlying problem is different.

NOTE: This is a closed-source application so dynamic linking is not an option for it requires distributing the source code to allow users to build the binaries on their own systems.

NOTE: I am currently trying to get this to compile with Linux via g++, but, I do intend to use mingw to distribute this application for Windows as well. Any advice that works there is preferable to Linux only advice, but, I can ask another question if I can't figure out that part from what will end up here.

NOTE: I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS x64 to compile.

Thank you in advance for even getting this far in this question. Sorry for the wall of text, but, I wanted to provide as much information as possible. I look forward to any answers!

Comment: "I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS x64 to compile."  nah, gotta drop back & build everything on Debian oldstable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Older Loki games did full static linking. Probably not worth it anymore, and far more difficult if you use external libraries.

Libraries are often not self-sufficient, requiring other libraries, .... Dynamic library have dependency information built-in, but static library is just an archive of `.o` files - it may depend on something but there is no special section that describes what extra libraries should be used. Your first error says that libSDL2.a uses symbol `sem_getvalue@@GLIBC_2.2.5` (`sem_getvalue` function, marked with glibc version) that cannot be resolved - most likely because you didn't add `-lpthread` to your linker flags. (`libSDL.so` depends on some version of pthrtead among other things - that's why you don't need to manually link with it if you don't use it directly).

GLEW should have no problems with static linking. You need to be more specific on errors you're getting. Maybe you got your libraries order wrong and linker cannot resolve GL functions. Need to see actual linking line and some 'undefined reference' errors to be more specific.

`pkg-config`'s `--static` flag should give you dependencies list (e.g. `-lpthread` should be in the output of `sdl2-config --static-libs` among many others), but it does not by itself produce static linking with given library. To request static linking, there are `-static` gcc flag that generates static executable (hard!) and `-Bstatic` *linker* flag to use static version for all libraries specified after it (so that way you can use some static libraries and some dynamic). `-Bdynamic` is a counterpart, asking to use dynamic libraries. E.g. to use static SDL and GLEW but dynamic GL linking line should be something like (if you use gcc to link, not ld directly) `gcc ${OBJECT_FILES} -Wl,-Bstatic -lSDL2 -lGLEW -Wl,-Bdynamic -lGL -lpthread -ldl -lm <everything else SDL2 requires - query with sdl2-config>`.

Your `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lasound` lines may have two reasons - static linking or related to the fact that you don't have development libraries installed (e.g. `libasound2-dev`, `libpulse-dev`, ... - at least they called that on debian, it is unlikely ubuntu have different names). 'User' libraries usually contains e.g. `libasound.so.2` but linker will not find this library as it have a version in it. Development package contains headers and symlink `libasound.so -> libasound.so.2` - that way linker knows what to use. If you use it indirectly via SDL2 - you don't need that, shared SDL2 already have a link to versioned library.

However there may be little point in doing so at all. You can distribute requred shared libraries with your software and use them either via `rpath` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable (maya, steam, etc... - almost everyone doing these this days). Moreover, even with static SDL2 end user can override SDL2 with their own (this is a feature intentionally implemented in SDL2). If there is a bug (or just very different environment) and your software is no longer gets updates - there is a chance that problem may be fixed by just replacing shared libraries. Would you really mind people running your program on wayland or mir if your original SDL2 had only X11 support?

`in such a way that it will run on any version of Linux it may find itself -- not just where it was originally compiled` is far more complicated, and honestly almost unrealistic (unless you have quite small program and use only very limited set of libraries with a good forward/backward compatibility - but even then it may be hard). One of big problems is glibc; usually it is a good idea to use lowest possible version of glibc to compile your program.

To sum it up, it is possible, but it does not help much.

Comment: When you say to distribute .so files with my application, which sounds like a good idea for the reasons you mentioned, how do I know what libraries I need to include and what libraries are safe to include? For example, do I need to include all of SDL's dependencies? If so, how do I find a list of all of them? Also, should I statically link libstdc++ as [this](https://insanecoding.blogspot.com/2012/07/creating-portable-linux-binaries.html) article recommends (for it seems that simply distributing my own may not work because it may not override the user's version)?

Comment: You could use [ldd](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ldd) to get dependencies list (works for both executable and shared libraries). It works recursively so what you get for executable is a complete list. `libc`, `libm`, `libdl` and `libpthread` are very likely to be present, but there are implications with glibc versions (genpfault's comment addresses that - this is what I meant by "lowest possible glibc" but forgot to expand further). Then you'll should apply some critical thinking - e.g. there is a little point it bringing `libX11` if your program only works in graphical mode.